# findViewById() may produce NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, inspection

I have many of these calls:

```
(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.items_no);
....
```

and AndroidStudio tells me that they may procude a `NullPointerException`:

> Method invocation `getView().findViewById(R.id.main_list_view)` may
>   produce `java.lang.NullPointerException` less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible
>   conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is
>   statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to
>   nullability contract violations.
>
> Variables, method parameters and
>   return values marked as `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` are treated as nullable
>   (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check
>   nullability contracts, e.g. report possible `NullPointerException`
>   errors.
>
> More complex contracts can be defined using `@Contract`
>   annotation, for example:
>
> `@Contract("_, null -> null")` — method returns null if its second argument is null 
>   `@Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null")` — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise
>
> `@Contract("true -> fail")` — a typical `assertFalse` method which throws an exception if true is passed to it
>
> The inspection can be configured to use custom `@Nullable`
>   `@NotNull` annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)

Luckily everithing works, but is there an improvement to this code I can made?

Comment: You want to write code that can't ever possibly through an NPE?

Comment: Are you using a ViewHolder pattern?

Comment: @takendarkk no, but I want to understand why ide tells me that it could happen

Comment: Because what happens if you give the method an id which doesn't exist? It returns null. There is nothing wrong at all.

Comment: I get that, **but is there an improvement to this code I can made?**

Comment: No. THERE. IS. NOTHING. WRONG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and it has been fixed in v24.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203345

You won't have any issues with android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity or android.app.Activity

Answer (score 2):

You **should ignore** the problem;

As @DanDar3 wrote -> getView() can return null and AndroidStudio highlights that.

But if you really want to make AndroidStudio happy - sure you can...:
Just assert view is not null:

```
View view = getView();
assert view != null;
(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.items_no);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is cause `getView()` may return null and is annotated as `@Nullable`, check out the sources and its JavaDoc - CTRL+Click on getView() call in your code.

```
/**
 * Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by {@link #onCreateView}),
 * if provided.
 * 
 * @return The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.
 */
@Nullable
public View getView() {
    return mView;
}
```

You can wrap your code yourself and check for null to have the warning go away, or otherwise place the cursor anywhere inside findViewById() call, wait couple of seconds for the lightbulb to show up (or press Alt+Enter) and then choose one of the suggested solutions.