# Disabling/Enabling a Continue button

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner when it comes to Android Studio/Java, so please forgive me if the question is kind of silly.

I have almost finished my first app, which is a simple riddle game; a question is being asked, and with the right answer you get to the next activity - and so on.
In the main menu, there are two options as usual: New Game and Continue. The Continue button works like a charm using shared preferences - when pressed, it takes you to the last question you didn't answer.

My problem is: I cannot make the Continue button disabled by default, and then enabled when the first question is answered. Well, the truth is I can disable it by using

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_with_logo);

    mContinueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ContinueButton);
    mContinueButton.setEnabled(false);
    ...
    }
```

but I haven't found a way to make it enabled later. I thought that by writing

```
if (!(question00Answered)) {

                mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, Question00.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
```

which is under "public void onClick" would make it work, but no, it doesn't. I still cannot press it even though the question was answered. So, any tips on what should I fix? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full script:

**MainMenuWithLogo.Java**

```
public class MainMenuWithLogo extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mStartInterrogationButton;
private VideoView mLogoprwto;
private Button mContinueButton;
MediaPlayer song;


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    song.release();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_with_logo);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chopin);
    song.start();
    song.setLooping(true);




    mLogoprwto = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.logoprwto);
    mLogoprwto.setVideoPath("android.resource://its_destination/"+R.raw.teloslogo);
    mLogoprwto.start();

    mLogoprwto.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mLogoprwto.start();
        }
    });

    mStartInterrogationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartInterrogationButton);
    mStartInterrogationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            startGame();

        }
    });

    mContinueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ContinueButton);
    mContinueButton.setEnabled(false);

    mContinueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Stage", MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean question00Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionZero", false);
            boolean question01Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionOne", false);
            boolean question02Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionTwo", false);




            if (!(question00Answered)) {

                mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionZero.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            } else if (!(question01Answered)) {

                mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            } else if (!(question02Answered)) {

                mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }else {

                mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, End.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });

}

private void startGame () {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Intro.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
finish();
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enabling the button on the wrong activity. Here is what your code is doing, in outline form:

1. onClick() runs for Activity #1's mContinueButton
2. Activity #1's mContinueButton is enabled
3. Activity #2 is started
4. Activity #1 (along with it's mContinueButton, which is the only enabled one at this point) is destroyed before activity #2 even opens up, b/c of the finish() call.

To fix, make your decision to call `setEnabled(true)` in onResume(). Remove the `setEnabled(true)` calls from `onClick()`. For example:

1. Disable the button.
2. Examine your preference Booleans. If any of them are false, call `setEnabled(true)`.
3. Set the button's `onClick()` handler. No calls to `setEnabled()` should be needed here (b/c that decision has already been made), but keep the if/then statements, and all the other code there, because you still need to choose which Activity to open.

Note that you've declared the `onClick()` handler as a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). The code in that function does not run when `onResume()` executes; it runs when a user clicks an enabled view.

Your yellow box will not cause any problems at the moment; refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671216/findviewbyid-may-produce-nullpointerexception) for a solution.

Comment: I start understanding the logic behind this. So, as far as the code above is concerned, I have to write it down like this:

 "mContinueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ContinueButton);
        mContinueButton.setEnabled(false);
        mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);" 

under onResume(), and remove the "mContinueButton.setEnabled(true);" lines from the onClick()? Or do I have to make changes to other activities too? Because I did what you said, but now the button is always enabled.

Also, mContinueButton.setEnabled(false); appears in a yellow box:  http://i.imgur.com/wfbjWPV.jpg

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer.